# How can i export my blender model from mysql database to three.js

Tags: php, three.js

Is there any way I can export my blender model from mysql database to three.js webpage through php? How can I upload my blender model to mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect(youraccessdata);
$result=mysqli_query($link,yourquery);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<script>
data="<?php echo $result[0]['data'];?>";
...
</script>
```

This accesses your mysql database and echos the result into the js variable data.to upload use the myql console or a tool like phpmyadmin or write it your own.